# SCDF stream (time) NOT picking composed-task-runner in local

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-batch-stream

in SCDF (2.6.3) tried to create stream to launch composite task, but not picking, what am I missing?

Composed task created name as **comp-task**: AA && BB
I can run manually run this composed task, it executed both AA and BB and exit normally.

When I tried to run through stream, it is not running at all even defined in cron.
My task definition:
`stream create ctr-stream-1 --definition "time --cron='0 0/5 0 ? * *' --task.launch.request.task-name=composed-task-launcher --task.launch.request.args=--graph=comp-task,--increment-instance-enabled=true | task-launcher-dataflow"`

My Environment details:

```
{
  "versionInfo": {
    "implementation": {
      "name": "spring-cloud-dataflow-server",
      "version": "2.6.3"
    },
    "core": {
      "name": "Spring Cloud Data Flow Core",
      "version": "2.6.3"
    },
    "dashboard": {
      "name": "Spring Cloud Dataflow UI",
      "version": "2.5.1"
    },
    "shell": {
      "name": "Spring Cloud Data Flow Shell",
      "version": "2.6.3",
      "url": "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-shell/2.6.3/spring-cloud-dataflow-shell-2.6.3.jar"
    }
  },
  "featureInfo": {
    "streamsEnabled": true,
    "tasksEnabled": true,
    "schedulesEnabled": true,
    "grafanaEnabled": false,
    "wavefrontEnabled": false
  },
  "securityInfo": {
    "isAuthenticationEnabled": false,
    "isAuthenticated": false,
    "username": null,
    "roles": []
  },
  "runtimeEnvironment": {
    "appDeployer": {
      "platformSpecificInfo": {},
      "deployerImplementationVersion": "2.5.2",
      "deployerName": "Spring Cloud Skipper Server",
      "deployerSpiVersion": "2.5.2",
      "javaVersion": "11.0.6",
      "platformApiVersion": "",
      "platformClientVersion": "",
      "platformHostVersion": "",
      "platformType": "Skipper Managed",
      "springBootVersion": "2.2.8.RELEASE",
      "springVersion": "5.2.7.RELEASE"
    },
    "taskLaunchers": [
      {
        "platformSpecificInfo": {},
        "deployerImplementationVersion": "2.4.1",
        "deployerName": "LocalTaskLauncher",
        "deployerSpiVersion": "2.4.1",
        "javaVersion": "11.0.6",
        "platformApiVersion": "Windows 10 10.0",
        "platformClientVersion": "10.0",
        "platformHostVersion": "10.0",
        "platformType": "Local",
        "springBootVersion": "2.2.8.RELEASE",
        "springVersion": "5.2.7.RELEASE"
      }
    ]
  },
  "grafanaInfo": {
    "url": "",
    "token": "",
    "refreshInterval": 15
  },
  "monitoringDashboardInfo": {
    "url": "",
    "token": "",
    "refreshInterval": 15,
    "source": "default-scdf-source"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to create a stream when you want to create/launch a composed task. This [page](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/feature-guides/batch/composed-task/#what-is-a-composed-task) walks you through how to create and launch a composed task as a **task** application.

If you want to schedule a composed task application, you also need to remember that **scheduling** a task application is not supported in **local** deployment.

Comment: Thanks a ton for response, just to clarify, I used stream (time app) here is only to schedule my composed task as task schedule is not supported in local deployment, can you please kindly advise, in local deployment, what are other ways to schedule composite tasks ?

Comment: I see. In this case, your approach is reasonable but you can find some related content here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-scheduler-quartz/pull/1 . Also, the properties you use for `time` source aren't valid and you need to check the supported properties.